# In css, :before {content: Lücke} gets transformed to :before content{content: L\FC cke}

Tags: css, angular

In my css, I tried to add the following:

```
.test:before {
    content: "Lücke"
}
```

In JS fiddle this wasn't a problem and I received the expected:
[image]

But in my Angular4 project, the result looked like this:

[image]

and when inspecting the styles in the chrome dev console, I found

```
.test:before {
    content: "L\FC cke";
}
```

Why does my Umlaut get messed up and how can I prevent this?

Comment: seems like a file encoding issue. Make sure your IDE/editor uses an Umlaut-compatible encoding for the file, such as UTF-8.

Comment: @jp-jee hm, when opening in atom editor it tells me it already is UTF8

Comment: The display in the dev console is actually a correct representation of the text! The space is a delimiter between the FC and the c, and it is not output. See [changed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yquu0zLp/). So that is not the cause of the space in the actual output. Hm.

Comment: @MrLister Hm interesting, any ideas what then is the problem?